# Apply findbugs on a main pom file

Tags: java, maven-3, pom.xml, multi-module

I have a multi module project and i want to run find bugs maven plugin on the total project and get the findbugs.xml output.
my main pom file is:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <modules>
            <module>../common-core</module>
            <module>../spark-monitoring-module</module>
            <module>../mass-analytics-connector-module</module>
            <module>../global-aggregation-job</module>
            <module>../location-aggregation-job</module>
            <module>../bdr-aggregation-job</module>
            <module>../activities-aggregation-job</module>
            <module>../recovery-aggregation-job</module>
            <module>../link-analysis-aggregation-job</module>
            <module>../spark-streaming-module</module>
            <module>../coordinates-to-mgrs-converter</module>
        </modules>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>all</id>
        <modules>
            <module>../common-core</module>             
            <module>../spark-monitoring-module</module>
            <module>../mass-analytics-connector-module</module>
            <module>../global-aggregation-job</module>
            <module>../location-aggregation-job</module>
            <module>../bdr-aggregation-job</module>
            <module>../activities-aggregation-job</module>
            <module>../recovery-aggregation-job</module>
            <module>../link-analysis-aggregation-job</module>
            <module>../spark-streaming-module</module>
            <module>../parquet-writer-sim</module>
            <module>../coordinates-to-mgrs-converter</module>
        </modules>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>act</id>
        <modules>
            <module>../common-core</module>
            <module>../bdr-aggregation-job</module>
            <module>../activities-aggregation-job</module>
        </modules>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

i have tried doing this:

```
<profiles>
<profile>
    <id>dev</id>
    <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
        <build>
    <pluginManagement>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <effort>Max</effort>
                    <failOnError>false</failOnError>
                    <findbugsXmlOutputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/findbugs</findbugsXmlOutputDirectory>
                    <threshold>Low</threshold>
                    <xmlOutput>true</xmlOutput>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>analyze-compile</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>check</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
    <modules>
        <module>../common-core</module>
        <module>../spark-monitoring-module</module>
        <module>../mass-analytics-connector-module</module>
        <module>../global-aggregation-job</module>
        <module>../location-aggregation-job</module>
        <module>../bdr-aggregation-job</module>
        <module>../activities-aggregation-job</module>
        <module>../recovery-aggregation-job</module>
        <module>../link-analysis-aggregation-job</module>
        <module>../spark-streaming-module</module>
        <module>../coordinates-to-mgrs-converter</module>
    </modules>
</profile>
<profile>
    <id>all</id>
    <modules>
        <module>../common-core</module>             
        <module>../spark-monitoring-module</module>
        <module>../mass-analytics-connector-module</module>
        <module>../global-aggregation-job</module>
        <module>../location-aggregation-job</module>
        <module>../bdr-aggregation-job</module>
        <module>../activities-aggregation-job</module>
        <module>../recovery-aggregation-job</module>
        <module>../link-analysis-aggregation-job</module>
        <module>../spark-streaming-module</module>
        <module>../parquet-writer-sim</module>
        <module>../coordinates-to-mgrs-converter</module>
    </modules>
</profile>
<profile>
    <id>act</id>
    <modules>
        <module>../common-core</module>
        <module>../bdr-aggregation-job</module>
        <module>../activities-aggregation-job</module>
    </modules>
</profile>

<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <effort>Max</effort>
                <threshold>Low</threshold>
                <xmlOutput>true</xmlOutput>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

but it doesn't generate any findbugx.xml file ,  Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: any maven experts in the crowd?

Comment: my solution was to add the following to the main pom file:
     `<build><plugins>
       <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
    <configuration>
     <findbugsXmlOutput>true</findbugsXmlOutput>
     <findbugsXmlWithMessages>true</findbugsXmlWithMessages>
     <xmlOutput>true</xmlOutput>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>
 </build>`